# Jboss EAP 6.3 threads get deadlock with log4j ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x, deadlock

After upgrading from Jboss 5 to Jboss EAP 6.3.0 we found an application to fail after some time running. Taking a look it started to grow the number of threads accepting HTTP requests but being unable to server them. After that a ThreadDump showed us a deadlock with log4j:

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"http-/0.0.0.0:39002-109":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000013d2a218 (object 0x00000000c1cc7aa8, a org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender),
  which is held by "http-/0.0.0.0:39002-12"
"http-/0.0.0.0:39002-12":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000000001456c128 (object 0x00000000c1cca400, a java.io.PrintStream),
  which is held by "http-/0.0.0.0:39002-74"
"http-/0.0.0.0:39002-74":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000013d2a218 (object 0x00000000c1cc7aa8, a org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender),
  which is held by "http-/0.0.0.0:39002-12"
```

Speaking with development team all references to log4j were removed inside the application leaving only the configuration on standalone.xml ir order to log some classes to some specific files, this is the relevant configuration regarding logging:

```
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
        <formatter>
            <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="DocumentalServices">
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="DocumentalServices.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="10m"/>
        <max-backup-index value="5"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="DataServices">
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="DataServices.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="10m"/>
        <max-backup-index value="5"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="Audit">
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="audit.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="10m"/>
        <max-backup-index value="5"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="com.documentation.framework.ws" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="DocumentalServices"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.documentation.framework.data" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="DataServices"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.documentation.framework.core.audit" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="Audit"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
```

Seems a bit strange the deadlock on ConsoleAppender, taking in mind we are not logging to console inside root-logger, just to FILE (server.log).

Answer (score 1):

Something has to be adding the log4j ConsoleAppender. It could be Spring as I know they do some logging trickery. During start-up you could try passing `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` which should disable JBoss EAP's attempts to configure log4j if a log4j.xml or log4j.properties file is found.

Another option might be to set the `add-logging-api-dependencies` to `false` in the logging subsystem. You'd need to include a log4j library in your deployment as it appears something is depending on it. Here's what the CLI would look like to change the default.

```
/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(name=add-logging-api-dependencies,value=false)
```

Note thought disabling this affects all deployments.

That said the issue is the way the log4j ConsoleAppender works. It always logs to `System.xxx` directly. JBoss EAP wraps `stdout` and `stderr` in a logger which is what leads to the deadlock.

There's a fix that should end up in a [6.4](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1211155) release at some point.

Comment: James, right now after working with Devel Team they removed all System.out.println from code and it seems the problem is not happening again. You're right, they are using spring for development.

Comment: FWIW the `System.out.println` statements should only be an issue if the log4j ConsoleAppender is being used. This should all be fixed in `org.jboss.logging:log4j-jboss-logmanager:1.1.2.Final` as well. It should be safe to replace that module library with the new version.